# CSS3 rotate3d with two angles

Tags: css

I am rotating a cube based on mouse position.

The mouse has an X co-ordinate and a Y co-ordinate on the screen at any time.

I am using jquery .mousemove() to determine the pixel co-ordinates, and then inside the mousemove function, I am adjusting the css rotate3d angle to move the object.

This is all working fine, but I would like to move the object based on the x and also y positions. Ideally like so..

```
'-webkit-transform': 'rotate3d(1,0,0,'+angleX+'deg)',
'-webkit-transform': 'rotate3d(0,1,0,'+angleY+'deg)',
```

But that doesn't work of course.

How do I get both axis to rotate different amounts at the same time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can combine transforms. The sum will be represented as a matrix3d function. Not really sure what you want to achieve, in your case the second transition overrides the first one. You could try:

```
'-webkit-transform': 'rotate3d(1,0,0,'+angleX+'deg)' + 'rotate3d(0,1,0,'+angleY+'deg)'
```

This can also problably be represented as only one transform if you tweak the [1,0,0] vector/axes

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly, had not idea that you could string them together like that.

Comment: You are welcomed. Be aware that the order of transforms matters.